# Convert country codes

Tags: php, country-codes

There are several methods on country codes.

I have a list of codes with 3-characters, like on this page:

http://www.fina.org/H2O/index.php?option=com_content&view=category&id=93:asia&Itemid=638&layout=default

**Is there a simple way to convert them to 2-characters?** Like "PT" from "POR" for Portugal.

Standard for 2-characters - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2

Thanks.

Comment: Good question, but I think you'll have to write one yourself or use some webservice.

Comment: you have a better chance of getting list or database, which have direct mapping PT->PORTUGAL, if you post this question in gis.stackexchange.com. then you don't have to do worry about converting 3 char code to 2 char code...

Comment: You can use this website: https://www.countryconversion.com/

Answer (score -5, accepted):

There is going to be no easy way because there is no particular scheme in the names of the country. For example `PT` from `POR` for `Portugal` and this can be different for other countries as well. You might want to create an array to hold two letters for each country.

**Example:**

```
$countries = array('PT' => 'Portugal', 'UK' => 'United Kingdom');
```

Comment: its very easy if you have an array for 2 digit <> 3 digit country codes

Answer (score 35):

There are some useful data files that you can get from http://country.io/data that'll help you:

- http://country.io/iso3.json - a map of ISO2 to ISO3 country codes
- http://country.io/names.json - a map of ISO2 country codes to country names

If you just want to go from 3 letter codes to 2 letter codes you can just flip the first map and use that. You could create a map that goes directly from 3 letter codes to country names by combing the files though. Here's a simple PHP example:

```
$codes = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://country.io/iso3.json'), true);
$names = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://country.io/names.json'), true);
$iso3_to_name = array();
foreach($codes as $iso2 => $iso3) {
    $iso3_to_name[$iso3] = $names[$iso2];
}

echo $names("PL"); // => "Poland"
echo $iso3_to_map("POL"); // => "Poland"
```

Comment: Call to undefined function json_deocde()

Comment: Sorry, fixed the typo. Should have been json_decode()

Comment: Do you also know of a list which provides 'ISO2 country codes to country names' in different languages? Like frensh, german, spanish, etc?

Comment: `$codes = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://country.io/iso3.json'), true);
$names = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://country.io/names.json'), true);
$iso3_to_name = array();
foreach($codes as $iso2 => $iso3) {
 $iso3_to_name[$iso3] = $names[$iso2];
}

echo $names["PL"]; // => "Poland"
echo $iso3_to_name["POL"]; // => "Poland"`

Answer (score 10):

I see that the question was asked seven years ago. Today I had the similar issue and found one good solution. Hope that this answer will be helpful to others who will have the same issue in the future.

There is a separate library which can be used https://github.com/thephpleague/iso3166

Then the solution would be straightforward. **$alpha3** is the three char representation of a country. And **alpha2** is two char representation of the country.

1. `$ composer require league/iso3166`
2. `$data = (new League\ISO3166\ISO3166)->alpha3($alpha3);`
3. Data looks as follows:

   ```
   [
     'name' => 'Netherlands',
     'alpha2' => 'NL',
     'alpha3' => 'NLD',
     'numeric' => '528',
     'currency' => [
       'EUR',
       ]
   ]
   ```
4. `$countryCodeInTwoChar = $data['alpha2']`

Answer (score 6):

Building on the other info here, here's a complete function ready to go:

```
function convertCountryAlphas3To2($code='') {
 $countries = json_decode('{"AFG":"AF","ALA":"AX","ALB":"AL","DZA":"DZ","ASM":"AS","AND":"AD","AGO":"AO","AIA":"AI","ATA":"AQ","ATG":"AG","ARG":"AR","ARM":"AM","ABW":"AW","AUS":"AU","AUT":"AT","AZE":"AZ","BHS":"BS","BHR":"BH","BGD":"BD","BRB":"BB","BLR":"BY","BEL":"BE","BLZ":"BZ","BEN":"BJ","BMU":"BM","BTN":"BT","BOL":"BO","BIH":"BA","BWA":"BW","BVT":"BV","BRA":"BR","VGB":"VG","IOT":"IO","BRN":"BN","BGR":"BG","BFA":"BF","BDI":"BI","KHM":"KH","CMR":"CM","CAN":"CA","CPV":"CV","CYM":"KY","CAF":"CF","TCD":"TD","CHL":"CL","CHN":"CN","HKG":"HK","MAC":"MO","CXR":"CX","CCK":"CC","COL":"CO","COM":"KM","COG":"CG","COD":"CD","COK":"CK","CRI":"CR","CIV":"CI","HRV":"HR","CUB":"CU","CYP":"CY","CZE":"CZ","DNK":"DK","DKK":"DK","DJI":"DJ","DMA":"DM","DOM":"DO","ECU":"EC","Sal":"El","GNQ":"GQ","ERI":"ER","EST":"EE","ETH":"ET","FLK":"FK","FRO":"FO","FJI":"FJ","FIN":"FI","FRA":"FR","GUF":"GF","PYF":"PF","ATF":"TF","GAB":"GA","GMB":"GM","GEO":"GE","DEU":"DE","GHA":"GH","GIB":"GI","GRC":"GR","GRL":"GL","GRD":"GD","GLP":"GP","GUM":"GU","GTM":"GT","GGY":"GG","GIN":"GN","GNB":"GW","GUY":"GY","HTI":"HT","HMD":"HM","VAT":"VA","HND":"HN","HUN":"HU","ISL":"IS","IND":"IN","IDN":"ID","IRN":"IR","IRQ":"IQ","IRL":"IE","IMN":"IM","ISR":"IL","ITA":"IT","JAM":"JM","JPN":"JP","JEY":"JE","JOR":"JO","KAZ":"KZ","KEN":"KE","KIR":"KI","PRK":"KP","KOR":"KR","KWT":"KW","KGZ":"KG","LAO":"LA","LVA":"LV","LBN":"LB","LSO":"LS","LBR":"LR","LBY":"LY","LIE":"LI","LTU":"LT","LUX":"LU","MKD":"MK","MDG":"MG","MWI":"MW","MYS":"MY","MDV":"MV","MLI":"ML","MLT":"MT","MHL":"MH","MTQ":"MQ","MRT":"MR","MUS":"MU","MYT":"YT","MEX":"MX","FSM":"FM","MDA":"MD","MCO":"MC","MNG":"MN","MNE":"ME","MSR":"MS","MAR":"MA","MOZ":"MZ","MMR":"MM","NAM":"NA","NRU":"NR","NPL":"NP","NLD":"NL","ANT":"AN","NCL":"NC","NZL":"NZ","NIC":"NI","NER":"NE","NGA":"NG","NIU":"NU","NFK":"NF","MNP":"MP","NOR":"NO","OMN":"OM","PAK":"PK","PLW":"PW","PSE":"PS","PAN":"PA","PNG":"PG","PRY":"PY","PER":"PE","PHL":"PH","PCN":"PN","POL":"PL","PRT":"PT","PRI":"PR","QAT":"QA","REU":"RE","ROU":"RO","RUS":"RU","RWA":"RW","BLM":"BL","SHN":"SH","KNA":"KN","LCA":"LC","MAF":"MF","SPM":"PM","VCT":"VC","WSM":"WS","SMR":"SM","STP":"ST","SAU":"SA","SEN":"SN","SRB":"RS","SYC":"SC","SLE":"SL","SGP":"SG","SVK":"SK","SVN":"SI","SLB":"SB","SOM":"SO","ZAF":"ZA","SGS":"GS","SSD":"SS","ESP":"ES","LKA":"LK","SDN":"SD","SUR":"SR","SJM":"SJ","SWZ":"SZ","SWE":"SE","CHE":"CH","SYR":"SY","TWN":"TW","TJK":"TJ","TZA":"TZ","THA":"TH","TLS":"TL","TGO":"TG","TKL":"TK","TON":"TO","TTO":"TT","TUN":"TN","TUR":"TR","TKM":"TM","TCA":"TC","TUV":"TV","UGA":"UG","UKR":"UA","ARE":"AE","GBR":"GB","USA":"US","UMI":"UM","URY":"UY","UZB":"UZ","VUT":"VU","VEN":"VE","VNM":"VN","VIR":"VI","WLF":"WF","ESH":"EH","YEM":"YE","ZMB":"ZM","ZWE":"ZW","GBP":"GB","RUB":"RU","NOK":"NO"}',true);
 $out = $countries[$code];
 return $out;
}
```

Comment: exactly what i needed, short and to the point, without wasting time reading external files.

Answer (score 4):

Without doing an actual lookup, there is no simple way: AFG (Afghanistan) becomes AF, while AND (Andorra) becomes AD, and BLR (Belarus) becomes BY... so you can't do any simple character manipulation to convert.

My suggestion would be to use a countrycode table, or add an extra column to any existing table, so that you hold both codes.

Comment: correct, thats why I recommend posting this question in gis.stackexchange.com

Comment: Adding an extra column is definatly the best approach

Answer (score 3):

Most of the other answers above are not direct answers. Let me try

I have tried **below code to convert 3-characters to 2-characters country code** using [API](http://country.io/iso3.json):

```
<?php
    $list=["BWA","SLV","TZA","BRB","IND","BES","ANT"];
    $iso3=file_get_contents('http://country.io/iso3.json');//load the country codes
    $iso3=json_decode($iso3,true);//convert json to associative array
    foreach($list as $k)
    {
        if($k=="ANT")//not defined in code list
            echo "AN";
        else
            echo array_search($k,$iso3); 
        echo "<br/>";
    }
?>
```

The country codes provided is in form of 2-iso(key):3-iso(value). So instead of searching for key, i searched by value and return the first corresponding key if successful.

**Output**

> BW
>
> SV
>
> TZ
>
> BB
>
> IN
>
> BQ
>
> AN

**Cons -**

`ANT` country code is not defined in code list.

**Reference** - [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Answer (score 1):

While this may be a lengthy and painful method, it may very well be worth your while writing a function that you can keep forever more, maybe this can point you in the right direction:

```
<?php
function myCodes($in, $type){
$out = "";
$long = array('portugal', 'united kingdom');
$short = array('pt', 'uk');
$in = strtolower(trim($in));
switch($type){
case 'long':$out = str_replace($short, $long, $in);break;
case 'short':$out = str_replace($long, $short, $in);break;
}
echo $out;
}

echo myCodes('United Kingdom', 'short'); //this will echo 'uk'
echo myCodes('UK', 'long'); //this will echo 'united kingdom'

?>
```

This will of course have a few drawbacks such as making sure that the arrays for long and short match up position wise, and you'll need to maintain the function as well.

Answer (score -1):

> $mapping['POR'] = 'PT';
>      $shortcode = $mapping[$longcode];

Answer (score -2):

In ruby you can get this done like this:
(get countryInfo.txt from http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/ )

```
require 'csv'
countries_iso3_map = {}
CSV.foreach('countryInfo.txt',:col_sep=>'   ',:row_sep =>:auto) do |row|
   next if row[0][0] == '#' #ignore comments section
   countries_iso3_map[row[0][0,2]]= row[1][0,3]
end
p countries_iso3_map['PT']
```